# Haskell- write map function using foldr

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write the map function using foldr. The problem is that when I ran this code :

```
> myMap f xs = foldr (\ acc x -> acc :(f x)) [] xs
```

I have the following problem:

> No instance for (Num [a0]) arising from a use of 'it'

but when I run

```
myMap f xs = foldr (\x acc-> (f x):acc) [] xs
```

It works perfectly. Any ideas why?

Comment: As a useful exercise, you can try to expand `map (+10) [1,2]` with both definitions and observe that the first one is not working, and possibly understand what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the type of foldr is

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

therefore the binary operation that foldr uses to traverse and accumulate the list 
has type `(a -> b -> b)`,it first take an element of the list (type `a`)then the accumulator (type `b`) resulting in an expression of type b.

So, your first myMap function does not work becuase you are using "acc" and "x" in reverse order.
You want to apply `f` to x then append it to the acummulator of type `b` ( a list in this case)

Answer (score 5):

The error you posted is not coming from your definition of `myMap`, it's coming from how you're using it.  The type of the first `myMap` is `([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]`, which does not match the type of `Prelude.map`.  In the second one you've swapped your variable names and also which one you're applying `f` to.  The compiler doesn't care what you name the arguments in your lambda being passed to `foldr`, so `foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc)` is identical to `foldr (\foo bar -> f foo : bar)`.  That may be what's tripping you up here.

The second one works because (to put it simply) it's correct.  In the first you're applying `f` to your accumulator list `x` (even though you have a variable named `acc` it's not your accumulator), so `f` must take a list and return a list.  In the second you're applying `f` to each element, then prepending that to your accumulator list.  If you had `myMap (+1)`, it would have the type

```
myMap (+1) :: Num [a] => [a] -> [a]
```

Which says that you must pass it a list of values `[a]` where `[a]` implements `Num`, and currently there is no instance for `Num [a]`, nor will there ever be.

TL;DR: In the first one you're applying your mapped function to your accumulator list, in the second one you're applying the mapped function to each element.